# Are OVAs in One Punch Man considered "canon" or "filler"?

Tags: one-punch-man

In another question asked here half year ago, it was pointed out that for 10 years since the appearence of One Punch Man, the powers heroes showed werent any kind of power. For example, no hero appeared who could manipulate ice or fire without artifacts , invisibility, people who could naturally fire beams, wind control, water control, animal control, etc. But now in OVA 1 of season 2,

> Heroes who can manipulate ice, fire and animals appeared

Should this be considered canon, or it's "filler", something the manga author didnt and wouldnt do for the manga?

Are OVAs in One Punch Man considered "canon" or "filler"?